# No decay of current in $RLC$ circuits?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

They are teaching alternating current in school. The book states that in an $RLC$ circuit, the instantaneous current is given as
$$i(t)=\frac{v_m}{\sqrt{R^2+(X_C-X_L)^2}}\sin(\omega t+\phi)$$
where $\tan\phi=\frac{X_C-X_L}R$, $v(t)=v_m\sin(\omega t)$. It's obvious from the equation that there is no damping of the current. The current is perfectly sinusoidal. This is also the case with RC circuit. Whereas, this is not the case in RL circuit, there is asymptotic growth in current.

**Why is that?**

To find more about the undergoing mathematical nuisance (the derivation in the book wasn't satisfactory enough for me, where we already assume that the current is sinusoidal), I tried [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%28x%29%2Ba*f%27%28x%29%2Bb*f%27%27%28x%29%3Dc*sin%28kx%29). It seems like although an exponential factor exists, it has no effect asymptotically, except in the RL circuit where it leads to current asymptotically growing from $0$.

**Then what's the problem?**

What doesn't make sense to me is that we know for a fact that resistance dissipates energy, while pure inductor and pure capacitor don't. Then how it can be the case that the steady-state current is sinusoidal as the resistance will still be there in the circuit to dissipate energy. An "idea" I have for this is that maybe the inductor and capacitor work to store some amount of the energy (like in LC oscillations) and that portion, somehow, isn't affected by the resistance.

Please help me understand the undergoing mechanics. And if possible, how can we, without using Wolfram|Alpha, solve for the exact equations of the instantaneous current in RLC,LC circuits with alternating voltage? A reference to required material would be enough, as I want to do that on my own. I can solve it for the RL,RC circuits using integration factor method, but don't what to do for the others.

Please correct me if I got anything wrong.

Comment: If you form a differential equation (for mathemactical "nuisance"), it will lead to a second order differential equation. You can solve it using any standard textbook which covers it.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know of such a book.

Comment: Any engineering mathematics textbook would cover it. I used Kreyszig during first year of college. You can also check it online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have left out something very important in presenting the problem: The source that provides power to the circuit.

If the source only provides power briefly (For example, during some interval $0 < t < T$), then you are right to expect the amplitude of the oscillation in the RLC circuit to decay for $t>T$ as the resistor dissipates the energy that has been provided by the source.

If the source provides power continuously (for example if you have a source voltage with the form $v_s=V\sin(\omega t + \phi)$ for all $t$, then the energy dissipated by the resistor can be replenished by the source, and you will find a steady-state solution that doesn't decay.

Presumably your book is discussing the second case when they found the result you are asking about.

Comment: Ah. Totally didn't think about the fact that there is a continuous, practically non finite, supply of power, when we write $v(t)=v_m\sin(\omega t)$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*Whereas, this is not the case in RL circuit, there is asymptotic growth in current.*
This is only true if the source is DC.

Your equation $i(t)=\dfrac{v_m}{\sqrt{R^2+(X_C-X_L)^2}}\sin(\omega t+\phi)$ is correct for all combination when there is a connection to an AC source, ie, $LCR,\,LC,\, LR, \, CR$ and the three circuit elements alone.
For those components which are not present you need to make their reactance/resistance equal to zero to have the correct equation for the current flowing in the circuit.

In the LR circuit with a DC supply the final (steady state) condition has the current reaching a maximum value and only the resistor dissipating electrical energy as heat.

With the AC source again the resistor is the only circuit element which dissipated electrical energy as heat whereas on average over a period of the AC the net electrical power dissipated is zero.
A steady state is reached after the transient current has decayed away.

Comment: Looks like I have a lot to research now, particularly transient current. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari Have a look at [Inductor connected to an AC source](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/728851/inductor-connected-to-an-ac-source/728865#728865).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that a proper treatment of this topic is available in your book. I will just try  to help you get an intuition into what is happening. As you have mentioned, I will use the fact that you already know how to solve RL and RC circuit.

First of all form a differential equation. If your equation contains charge, differentiate it. It will become current (and the equation will become second order)

Here is the intuition, our input is in form of sin (or cos). After some time, all voltages and current are going to be in form of sin (or cos) of the same frequency as input! Think about it. You apply sin force to any system. We can imagine that after some time the whole system would be oscillating with same frequency!

Assume a sinusoidal current of same frequency as input and substitute. You will be able to solve the equations directly.